# Declaring an array of enumerated types

Tags: system-verilog

I want to do the following:

```
typedef enum {a, b, c} my_type_e;
typedef enum {receive, transmit} dir_e;

class my_class #(type my_type_e);
  my_type_e variable_name;
endclass
```

But I want to make "variable_name" an array using dir_e as indices.  For example

```
my_class class_h;
class_h.variable_name[rx] = a;
```

or

```
my_class class_h;
class_h.variable_name[tx] = c;
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to declare an associative array.

```
class my_class #(type my_type_e);
  my_type_e variable_name[dir_e];
endclass

my_class class_h;
class_h.variable_name[receive] = a;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use parameters I wouldn't have the type parameter match an existing type. Also, some simulators still don't support not having a default.

```
typedef enum {a, b, c} my_type_e;
typedef enum {receive, transmit} dir_e;

class my_class #(type T=my_type_e, type K=dir_e);
  T variable_name[K];
endclass

my_class class_h;
class_h.variable_name[receive] = a;
```